# minidump using google breakpad fails to show line number where the application gets the crash

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, google-breakpad

I got minidump file for my application on a crash. But it is not giving me details like function name and line number. Output is as follows

```
Operating system: Linux
                  0.0.0 Linux 3.3.8-2.2 #1 SMP Thu May 12 13:30:26 UTC 2016 mips
CPU: mips
     2 CPUs

Crash reason:  SIGSEGV
Crash address: 0x0
Process uptime: not available

Thread 0 (crashed)
 0  breakpad_test + 0x3a8c
     gp = 0x0000000000433490    sp = 0x000000007fd53c88
     fp = 0x000000007fd53c88    ra = 0x0000000000403a7c
     pc = 0x0000000000403a8c    s0 = 0x000000000042c020
     s1 = 0x000000007fd53ce0    s2 = 0x0000000000000000
     s3 = 0x0000000000510cc8    s4 = 0x00000000004f8008
     s5 = 0x0000000000510d08    s6 = 0x0000000000000000
     s7 = 0x00000000004eac50
    Found by: given as instruction pointer in context
 1  breakpad_test + 0x3c70
     sp = 0x000000007fd53cb0    fp = 0x000000007fd53cb0
     ra = 0x0000000000403c78    pc = 0x0000000000403c70
    Found by: stack scanning
 2  libc-2.19.so + 0x1ba70
     sp = 0x000000007fd53d08    fp = 0x000000007fd53d08
     ra = 0x0000000076d5da78    pc = 0x0000000076d5da70
    Found by: stack scanning
 3  libpthread-2.19.so + 0x3e18
     sp = 0x000000007fd53d1c    fp = 0x000000007fd53d18
     ra = 0x0000000076ee7e20    pc = 0x0000000076ee7e18
    Found by: stack scanning
 4  ld-2.19.so + 0x1140
     sp = 0x000000007fd53dd0    fp = 0x000000007fd53de4
     ra = 0x000000007710d148    pc = 0x000000007710d140
    Found by: stack scanning


Loaded modules:
0x00400000 - 0x0041afff  breakpad_test  ???  (main)  (WARNING: No symbols, breakpad_test, 000000000000000000000000000000000)
0x76d42000 - 0x76ee1fff  libc-2.19.so  ???  (WARNING: No symbols, libc-2.19.so, B5374A28E4B2C3C877040AFB9B789B840)
0x76ee4000 - 0x76f0ffff  libpthread-2.19.so  ???  (WARNING: No symbols, libpthread-2.19.so, DAE5F3C6A7ED15218C085E10F0DDFFD50)
0x76f12000 - 0x76f51fff  libgcc_s.so.1  ???
0x76f52000 - 0x76feafff  libm-2.19.so  ???
0x76fec000 - 0x77103fff  libstdc++.so.6.0.19  ???
0x7710c000 - 0x77130fff  ld-2.19.so  ???  (WARNING: No symbols, ld-2.19.so, 844E9AC8CBD82909F65336ED3619228F0)
```

These are the steps i am using to see the output of dump

```
dump_syms ~/test/breakpad_test ~/test/ > breakpad_test.sym
head -n1 breakpad_test.sym
mkdir -p ./symbols/breakpad_test/6B504121E11042222534D706EFF02E490
mv breakpad_test.sym ./symbols/breakpad_test/6B504121E11042222534D706EFF02E490/
minidump_stackwalk 521a04eb-9a79-03d7-4aa11cee-55c2136e.dmp ./symbols/ > walkthru
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Me the same :(.i think you are following this tutorial : https://github.com/JPNaude/dev_notes/wiki/Using-Google-Breakpad-with-Qt   did you fix this ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I couldnt fix that one. But I have noticed that there is some compiler dependency. I was cross compiling for a platform with its tool chain which ended up in this issue. I tried the same with the gcc compiler available with my ubuntu and it was working. So I guess my platform compiler was removing the symbols as part of optimization.